# Android App development for image recognition using Caffe

Tags: android, server, caffe, flask-restful

I am working on a project in which the android app user is suppose to take an image as input and at the back end I have caffe's deployment.py file which takes an image as input and gives category (the image belongs to ) as output.
Now How should I connect both or how should I make my server side so that when the android app queries it goes to caffe and caffe gives category name as output which should be shown on android app.
I am novice to android app development.Please suggest if there are any sources I should read from.
can Flask-Restful be helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [repository](https://github.com/sh1r0/caffe-android-lib). It's caffe ported to android. They have a sample app as well [here](https://github.com/sh1r0/caffe-android-demo). [Here](https://github.com/malreddysid/sudoku_android) is something I worked on a while ago. It might be useful to you.